# handlebarsjs - how to use include in place of repeated code

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

After a lot of effort I have implemented [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to a test site that displays users data as they enter it.

To display the users input in different templates styles, I have had to repeat the same [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) code several times in the same form.

**Is there a way to place the repeated handlebars code in an external page and then  include this external page in place of the repeated handlebars code?**

I am unsure of the syntax or even if this approach is possible with [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (I have tried several things - but cannot get this working).

Here is the culled repeated code that I have:

```
{{# if address_style_one_line }}

    {{! address is to be displayed across one line - replaced line breaks with line space }}
    {{# if address_style_01 }}
    ....
    {{else}}
        {{# if address_style_02 }}
        ....

{{else}}

    {{! address is to be displayed across more than one line - use this format as the template for the address scross one line style }}
    {{# if address_style_01 }}
    ....
    {{else}}
        {{# if address_style_02 }}
        ....

{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with partials. Partials allow you to reuse templates within other templates.

**Documentation:**

- Basic usage: http://handlebarsjs.com/#partials
- Other features: http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

Rough example:

```
<script id="address-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{# if address_style_one_line }}
        {{> address}}
    {{else}}
        {{> address}}
    {{/if}}
</script>

<script id="address-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    // repeated template goes here

    {{! address is to be displayed across one line - replaced line breaks with line space }}
    {{# if address_style_01 }}
       ....
    {{else}}
        {{# if address_style_02 }}
       ....
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        // register partial
        Handlebars.registerPartial("address", $("#address-partial").html());
    });
</script>
```